# Functions for which there is a positive real number $a$ such that $ f'\left(\frac ax\right)=\frac x{f(x)}$ for all $x>0.$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find all differentiable functions $f: (0,\infty)\mapsto (0,\infty)$ for which there is a positive real number $a$ such that
> $ f'\left(\frac ax\right)=\frac x{f(x)} $
> for all $x>0.$

---

I found a [solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h64444p383355) which goes like this:

> Let
> $g(x)=f\left(\frac ax\right)f(x)$
> so
> $g'(x)=f\left(\frac ax\right)f'(x)-\frac{a}{x^2}f'\left(\frac ax\right)f(x)=f\left(\frac ax\right)f'(x)-\frac{a}{x}$
> $g'(\frac{a}{x})=f\left(x)f'(\frac ax\right)-x=0$ so $g(x)$ is constant.
> Suppose
> $$f\left(\frac ax\right)f(x)=c$$
> $$f\left(\frac ax\right)=\frac{c}{f(x)}$$
> $$f'\left(\frac ax\right)=\frac{-f'(x)c}{f(x)^2}$$ So the initial condition becomes
> $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{a}{c}$
> so
> $f(x)=Bx^r$, $r=\frac{a}{c}$, $B>0$

---

At the very starting, they take a function $g(x)=f\left(\frac ax\right)f(x)$ and goes on to proving its constant which greatly simplifies the problem. Can I get to know what could have been the motivation behind taking such a function into consideration?

Comment: I think it's natural to look for a function $h$ such that $h'(x)=f'(a/x)$, or $h'(x)=f'(a/x)f(x)$, or $h'(x)=f'(a/x)f(x)-x$; and they found one. They didn't include the trial-and-error process that led them to this function, but that's what they were looking for and they found it.

Comment: There's an error is in computing $f'(a/x)$ at the end. The left side should be $$-\frac a{x^2}f'(a/x)=\dots.$$ Otherwise, you have differentiated the left side by $a/x$ and the right side by $x.$

Comment: And the last line should be $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac ac\cdot \frac1x.$ And you don't actually require $B>0.$ $B<0$ works just as well.